# Airport location identification from 1960s photo?

Tags: airliner, airport

Can anyone identify the airport location in this photo?

It would have been taken in late 1962 or early 1963 just before this DC-8 N9609Z took on its Canadian registration CF-TJL in April 1963.

There is some speculation that it is Long Beach airport or Miami airport. I think it is neither, due to the lack of palm trees, and because of what appears to be snow visible in the photo.

The sign in the background says “Home of Coppertone” which leads me to believe it might be Newark, New Jersey since Wippany, New Jersey is the head office for Coppertone.

I believe this is the first DC-8F "Jet Trader" convertible freighter. There is a sign on a tripod near the front entrance which may mean it is part of some public display.

[image]

Alex McPhee photo collection

Comment: I agree, that's snow.  Seems to be a mix of evergreens and hardwoods on the horizon.  That building with the globe on top might be distinctive enough though whether it's a newspaper or a radar I can't tell.

Comment: Do snowy places sell a lot of Coppertone? Versus sandy places?

Comment: Coppertone headquarters suggests Whippany NJ, which suggests KMMU in Morristown NJ.

Comment: KMMU is a municipal airport and the runways are too short for a DC-8.

Comment: Is that a roller coaster on the horizon at the right? Are any of the other signs legible in the original photo?

Comment: Why can't the plane be in Canada? If that's the case, Coppertone may have been based in Montreal (this information must be checked), but the thin line in the background is unlikely to be a rollercoaster: Montreal had its own amusement park only in 1967, after the expo.

Comment: The layout seen in the picture does not match anyting with 1960's Newark. There was no apron next to a road with buildings on the other side as in the pic.

Comment: Coppertone's Canada headquarters is indeed in Montreal near Trudeau airport, at least today. But this doesn't really look like Montreal, then or now. And the building looks more like a factory than an office anyway.

Comment: Based on a record of the airports where Trans-Canada Airlines operated, the US choices are: Boston, Massachusetts; New York City, New York; Chicago, Illinois; Cleveland, Ohio; Tampa, Florida and Detroit (Windsor). (TCA also operated to many other destinations in Canada, the Caribbean and Europe).

Comment: What makes this detective work extremely difficult, is that even though the time frame is really limited (acft re-registration), airports and their surroundings rarely survive without massive changes for more than a decade.  The area we see in the picture may now be covered by a new terminal, runway, parking lot etc...

Comment: I was thinking the "roller coaster" in the background could have been Six Flags/Great Adventure in Jackson Twp, NJ. Unfortunately, GA didn't open until 1974 and it's nearly 50 miles away as the crow flies, so that's right out. It does seem that "Coppertone manufacturing locations 1962" might be a fruitful search.

Comment: It looks like there is snow behind the plane, so not in Florida, at least not Miami. I guess this is a scan, do you have a better resolution  to see car plates or inscriptions on other buildings on the left side?

Comment: Hmm. That *could* be Burke Lakefront Airport in Cleveland OH.

Comment: That's not snow -- it's sand. That's Miami. Australian pines in the background, palm trees in the background, Coppertone signs, and the completely board flat landscape. I grew up in Miami and recognized it instantly.

Comment: @CareyGregory -- What are we seeing in the foreground, in front of the engine nacelles-- are those not tire tracks in a thin layer of snow or slush?  Or has sand gotten blown onto the pavement?

Comment: @quietflyer Must be sand because snow very rarely falls where palm trees grow. Look at the right side of the photo above the tail. See the big Coppertone sign in the background? Just to the right of that sign are two palm trees. In fact, using google maps I can pretty much pinpoint [that aircraft's location](https://www.google.com/maps/place/25%C2%B047'53.2%22N+80%C2%B015'54.9%22W/@25.7981068,-80.2667912,696m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d25.7981068!4d-80.2652404).

Comment: @CareyGregory -- re "Just to the right of that sign are two palm trees."-- I believe you are right; no one else spotted those.  Write up your answer and collect your bonus--

Comment: You are very close but I'm not sure about the exact spot-- there is the shadow of what appears to be a building behind the camera-- but basically I think you've got it nailed--

Answer (score 26):

The airport is Miami International. I base this on the following factors:

1. **Personal familiarity:** I lived in Miami from 1959 until 1974 and have been to MIA many times. I recognized that view the moment I saw the photo.
2. The **white sandy soil** that many mistook for snow. It is [ubiquitous in
   south Florida](https://floridahikes.com/florida-habitats/scrub) and any bare ground you see is likely to be bright
   white, as seen in the dirt road behind the aircraft. Some light sand
   is also blown across the tarmac, which some people also mistook for
   snow.

   [image]
3. **Palm trees:** Just to the right of the large, elevated Coppertone sign there are unmistakably two palm trees.

   [image]
4. **Australian pines:** The horizon is dotted with Australian pines, which are extremely common in south Florida. (Or were in 1963. I believe a disease wiped out many of them in the 1970s.)

   [image]
5. **The Coppertone billboards:** You couldn't swing a dead cat in Miami in the 1960s without hitting one of those signs, particularly near the airport.

   [image]
6. **The distant background:** MIA is west of downtown Miami, so this photo is looking east (slightly ENE). You can see downtown Miami in the center of the photo, and the hotels of Miami Beach more distant farther to the right. Both are correctly placed relative to the airport.

   [image]
7. **The terrain:** South Florida is an ancient reef, so it's utterly board flat. There is literally no such thing as a hill in Miami unless it's man-made, and the terrain in this photo fits precisely.**
8. **The Shell gas station:** As you can see in the Google Maps [satellite view](https://www.google.com/maps/place/25%C2%B047%2753.2%22N+80%C2%B015%2754.9%22W/@25.7976069,-80.2657762,403m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d25.7981068!4d-80.2652404), there is a Shell gas station on the corner of NW 25th St. That location was a Shell gas station in 1963 as well.

[image]

I would estimate that the plane is parked approximately [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/25%C2%B047%2753.2%22N+80%C2%B015%2754.9%22W/@25.7976069,-80.2657762,299m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d25.7981068!4d-80.2652404), though it may be closer to the large building as pointed out in comments.

Comment: Well done - that is an awesome answer & research!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.